# React hook useRef not working with styled-components and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, styled-components

I've some problem using the `useRef` hook with a styled component.

Linter alerts me that `Object is possibly 'null'` inside the didMount `useEffect`. Any idea about this?

#### This is not a duplicate for 2 reason:

- The old answer refers to the `ref` used in a class component, that was the only way to use it before React hooks,
- The `innerRef` props isn't supported anymore in the current version of styled components.

Here's a sample snippet of my component:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledInput = styled.input`
  background: transparent;
`

const MyForm = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus(); //Object is possibly 'null'
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyledInput ref={inputRef}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: @MatthewBarbara innerRef isn't supported anymore by styled components

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've finally found a solution:

```
const inputRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;
```

---

It works for me:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const StyledInput = styled.input`
  background: transparent;
`

const MyForm = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputRef && inputRef.current) {
      inputRef.current.focus();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyledInput ref={inputRef}/>
  );
}
```

Comment: You can actually pass `HTMLInputElement` in the typing parameters: `const inputRef = <HTMLInputElement>useRef()` instead of using `as`

Comment: i keep getting an error "Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?"

Comment: `useRef` has a generic allowing to modify the type additionally to the default value:
`const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>()` results in `React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null | undefined>`.

Comment: How do you do this in plain Javascript?

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative to the current accepted answer, you can also do:

```
const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your inputRef in the array argument of useEffect and let's see if that works, you aren't guaranteed to have a `.current` in your ref, so you should run the effect every time inputRef changes